# Show some background color for an <img> where <img> size is less than the page

Tags: html, css

I am using the following css for an image - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yA33Q/)

```
img {
border: 3px solid #ddd;
margin-left: auto;
display: block;
margin-right: auto;
background: red;
}
```

Here is the output of the same  - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yA33Q/)

[image]

But I want something like this

[image]

**What I Want ?**

I want that if the image is not the full width then the remaining space as shown in the picture above should be filled with some color.

**What I Know And Don't Want To Use**

I know I can easily get this done by wrapping the image tag in a div and setting the div's background with that color. This I cannot do because this css change I am doing for a blog, and this blog already has so many post with it, I don't want to open each post and wrap each img with a div.

Was thinking there might be a simple CSS hack which I might be missing out on. Please advice.

Only CSS, no jQuery please.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the image width, you can achieve this with padding.

Since your image width is 379px, I can set the horizontal padding to `calc(50% - 190px)`

`(379 / 2 = 189.5, round up to 190)`

```
img{
    padding: 0px calc(50% - 190px);
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yA33Q/2/)

Comment: Interesting, but I do not know the image width. Because this is for a blog where multiple images of different sizes will be there. Is there any alternative for this ?

Comment: You could fix the image width as a percentage, like `width: 80%; padding: 0 10%;` [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yA33Q/3/)

Comment: the image pixelates, for smaller images it ll be even more bad.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the only way to do it with strict CSS (that I know of). If you want a dynamic solution for all sizes, you need jQuery/JS.

Comment: @Yasser The only other thing I can come up with is to use box-sizing to constrain the image width with padding. However this will produce the same problem as before, as you are essentially defining how wide the padding will be as a static number. [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yA33Q/5/)